# SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input at JSON.parse (<anonymous>) - Angular And spring Boot

Tags: javascript, angular, spring, typescript, spring-boot

Good morning, I got this error in google chrome but not in mozilla firefox. In google chrome my response doesn't come with a body but mozilla do. If someone can help me, i really don't know why this is happen. The response is the same but in mozilla is working but google chrome don't.
I use spring and angular.
Body come empty on google chrome.
[image: Body come empty]

In mozilla body appears normally. I don't really know what is happen.
[image]

My code in angular.

```
return this.http.get(`${this.resourceUrl}/analisando`, options)
        .map(res => {
             console.log(res);
             return res.json();
```

Comment: Sounds like Mozilla is being more strict on the JSON string that the service is providing. Without being able to inspect an example of your JSON string it's going to be hard to pin-point the issue.

Comment: It looks like your response (body) is wrapped in an array. Maybe this is the problem